# Axioms of countability in topology

Tags: general-topology

On Encyclopedia of Mathematica I find the definition of the two axioms of countability in topology.

[First][1] axiom:

(...)A topological space satisfies the first axiom of countability if the defining system of neighbourhoods of every point has a countable base. (...)

[Second][2] axiom:

(...)Topological spaces satisfy the second axiom of countability if they possess a countable base. (...)

I cannot grasp the difference between them. The first axiom reads that a topological space must have a set of neighbourhoods where every point has a countable base.
The second axiom says that a topological space must have a countable base.

What is the difference, in few words?

Thanks
[1]: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/First_axiom_of_countability
[2]: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Second_axiom_of_countability

Comment: Do you understand the difference between "you can buy anything in the store for a dollar" and "you can buy the whole store for a dollar"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the first countability axiom. A space $X$ is first-countable iff there is a countable local basis at every $x\in X$. The countable basis **depends on $x$** and only works for neighborhoods of $x$. A space $X$ is second-countable iff there is a countable basis for the **whole space $X$**. A second-countable space is always first-countable, but not the reverse.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies everything..

Comment: I should add that a "basis of neighborhoods" and a "base" are different things. Every basis is a basis of neighborhoods, but the converse is not true. When Ricky says "a basis at every $x$", it means "basis of neighborhoods".

Comment: Yes, I admit it's a bit misleading. Better terminology should be local basis or neighborhood basis.